# php concatenation operator dot or comma?

Tags: php

my first post here.

I've been using php for few years, but not into it for the last couple of years.

I just started university and in a lecture yesterday there was en example looking like:

```
$b = "HTML";
$a = "test ", $b , "printing";
echo $a;
```

so the operator using to concatenate strings and variable is the comma ,
I've ALWAYS used the . dot. Never knew I could use the comma.
I asked the lecturer and the answer was pretty vague.

Now I am researching on the manual and I found:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

is it possible to use the , ???

Comment: The comma only works in echos.

Comment: you should get syntax error in your example.

Comment: sorry for the duplicate, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Your code shouldn't work normally.

Answer (score 0):

It's `.` for Concatenation.

Your code should to be as,

```
$b = "HTML";
$a = "test" . $b . "printing";
echo $a;
```

Output :

```
testHTMLprinting
```

For whitespace, you should use

```
$b = "HTML";
$a = "test" . " " . $b . " " . "printing";
echo $a;
```

Output :

```
test HTML printing
```

Comment: or `$a = "test {$b} printing";` :)

Comment: thanks.. I always used the . 
but is it right that we can use the , with echo?
is there any official documentation? I cannot find on the php manual